# Join column with null values in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity as following :

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgenx_gx")
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String lastname;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Organization organization;

 }
```

And it's dto :

```
public class UserDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String organizationName;
    private Country country;

}
```

Using JPA Criteria API I want to select all users from database so I did as following :

```
final CriteriaBuilder builder = getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<UserDTO> query = builder.createQuery(UserDTO.class);
final Root<User> from = query.from(User.class);
Join<User, Organization> joinOrg = from.join(User_.organization, JoinType.LEFT);
query.multiselect(from.get(User_.id), from.get(User_.name), from.get(User_.lastname),
                 joinOrg.get(Organization_.name), from.get(User_.country));
query.distinct(true);

return getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

This problem is it will return only users where country is not null, because the generated query contains this : `inner join Country on User.country=Country.id`
Which has to be left join instead.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: For the benefit of those of us with lots of SQL but little JPA knowledge, can you explain the provenance of the underscore-suffixed versions of the entities (i.e. `User_`)?

Comment: Can you add the Role Class.

Comment: @JimGarrison they're generated by an annotation processor. See https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html

Comment: _User\_.organization_?

Comment: @JimGarrison those are the Meta Model Classes. Once the classes have been generated you can refer to fields in Entity objects using the meta model classes. The meta model class has the same name as the Entity class with an underscore appeneded.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli my mistake can you check the question again it's `User` and not `Role`

Comment: @pirho yes it's a field inside the `User` entity

Comment: If you are using country.id as a filter to be matched with user country then why should it return a user with a null country?

Comment: One solution might be to use `Or` and add another match for user.country=null

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki This works fine with OPENPA/Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to force `JoinType.LEFT` by adding a join for that also, like:

```
Join<User, Country> joinCountry = from.join("country", JoinType.LEFT);   
query.multiselect(from.get("id"), from.get("name"), from.get("lastname")
                              ,joinOrg.get("name"), joinCountry );
```

Anyway this problem might be elsewhere since I could not re-produce this on my environment.